# secure way to emulate hx-swap without sending get requests?

Tags: innerhtml, htmx

I have a header that when user clicks it it sends a request to fetch some social media links

```
<h3 class='header1' hx-get="/social" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#content_div" >My Social</h3>
```

The request then replaces the current `content_div` with

```
<div id="content_div">
    <div class="Socials">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/blah/blah"><font color="#007cc4"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></font></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/blah"><font color="#007cc4"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></font></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah-blah-blah/"><font color="#007cc4"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></font></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I like the functionality of this but I don't like the fact that I have to do a GET request to do this since the `socials` div is small and doesn't require any backend data. I can do this with some javascript by using the `innerHTML` attribute:

```
<h3 class='header1' hx-on:click="document.getElementById('content_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('socials').innerHTML;">My Socials</h3>

<div id='socials' style="display:none">
    <div class="Social-media fade-in">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231985/kkawabat" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/kkawabat" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kan-kawabata-8b4106a2/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

However using `innerHTML` could be a [security concern.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations)

In summary, how do I get the same result as the first line of code but without unnecessary server request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cloning the nodes directly. Perhaps:

```js
document.getElementById('content_div').replaceChildren(...document.getElementById('socials').cloneNode(true).childNodes);
```

A slightly more concise version is possible if you use the HTML [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element, which is designed for this type of scenario:

```js
document.getElementById('content_div').replaceChildren(document.getElementById('socials').content.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<template id='socials'>
    <div class="Social-media fade-in">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231985/kkawabat" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/kkawabat" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kan-kawabata-8b4106a2/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If your project has the `htmx` global variable available, then it includes a wrapper around `document.querySelector` and further improvements to conciseness can be achieved, e.g.
`htmx.find('#content_div').replaceChildren(htmx.find('#socials').content.cloneNode(true));`